# Problems with Suffix Icon of TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I have a `TextFormField` with a suffix icon, which is used as `IconButton`:

```
TextFormField(
  autocorrect: false,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: widget.icon,
    isDense: true,
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
      onPressed: () {...}                 
    )
  ),     
  controller: _controller,
  maxLines: null,
)
```

My problem is, the suffix icon increased the height of the text field:

[image]

(furthermore there is too much space between the end of the text and the icon):

[image]

I tried different approaches to avoid this, but nearly everything failed. Finally I found a possible solution here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21908#issuecomment-516434465

So, I tried to use an `IntrinsicHeight` widget as mentioned:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: TextFormField(...)
)
```

Indeed, it normalized the height of my `TextFormField`, but now there is something with the wordwrap/line break:

[image]

As you can see, the multiline adjustment is not working properly anymore, it is nearly indetermined to when it will expand.

So: Do you have any idea how to solve my initial problem with the suffix icon and the resulting text field height? Or do you now how to fix the multiline issue when using the `IntrisicHeight`?

Comment: did you tried inkwell or GestureDetector Widget instead of IconButton ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use `suffixIconConstraints` to reduce padding https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/50058 
Step 2: use `InkWell` wrap `Icon` and set `Icon` size

```
TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 5,
                      minHeight: 5,
                    ),
                    isDense: true,
                    suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 2,
                      minHeight: 2,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        child: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 14), onTap: () {})),
                controller: _controller1,
                maxLines: null,
              ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  TextEditingController myController1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _controller1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 5,
                      minHeight: 5,
                    ),
                    isDense: true,
                    suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 2,
                      minHeight: 2,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        child: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 14), onTap: () {})),
                controller: _controller1,
                maxLines: null,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 5,
                      minHeight: 5,
                    ),
                    isDense: true,
                    suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 2,
                      minHeight: 2,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        child: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 14), onTap: () {})),
                controller: _controller2,
                maxLines: null,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks great! Two questions: What does the minWidth/minHeight exactly do? I cannot see any difference when I change it to 10 or even to null. Second: Is it possible to add small space to the right of the icon? Should I use a Container inside the InkWell?

Comment: In source code, Wrap icon with ConstrainedBox and BoxConstraints https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/610dc170d95fadb5dff8f72022ca9dd528f45540/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L2243

Comment: As pull request describe This is particularly useful when isDense is set to true, which allows the icon sizes to be smaller than 48x48px.

Comment: I use padding to add space. you can check it. suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
                          child: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 10),
                        ), onTap: () {}))

Comment: exactly what I needed to use. Suffix was causing alignment issues, suffixIcon seems to do the work.

Comment: Look nice, I also check example of that - http://techandroidhub.com/prefix-and-suffix-icon-in-textfield/

Answer (score 0):

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.red),
                                        borderRadius:
                                            const BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(10))),
                                    labelText: "Current password",
```

//change IconButton to GestureDetector

```
                                    suffixIcon:     GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        controller.isObscureOld.value =
                                        !controller.isObscureOld.value;
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(
                                        !controller.isObscureOld.value
                                            ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                                            : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                                        size: 26,
                                        color: ColorConstants.grayLight,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```